# Laravel adding normal PHP package

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a new Laravel 5.6 application. I wanted to see if I could an existing library ([see link](https://github.com/adriangibbons/php-fit-file-analysis)). The idea is that I could use the controller to parse the fit file and display the data in a view.

I have added the package adriangibbons/php-fit-file-analysis in my composer.json file.

Then the documentation mentions:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';  // this file is in the project's root folder
    $pFFA = new adriangibbons\phpFITFileAnalysis('fit_files/my_fit_file.fit');
?>
```

How can this be done in Laravel? Normally I would add something in the 'providers' section of my app.php but don't know how I can add the above snippet in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel already loads the Composer autoload file so can skip the require line. Adding a provider to the providers array in app.php allows Laravel specific packages to hook into Laravel features/config. Since this package is not Laravel specific you can just use it directly in your controller.

```
$pFFA = new \adriangibbons\phpFITFileAnalysis('fit_files/my_fit_file.fit');
```

Or a slightly more "Laravel" way

add `use adriangibbons\phpFITFileAnalysis` at the top of your controller. Then in the method add:

```
$pFFA = new phpFITFileAnalysis(storage_path('fit_files/my_fit_file.fit'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing that gives me: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Fitfile\adriangibbons\phpFITFileAnalysis' not found" error.

Comment: @wiwa1978 Did you run `composer update` after adding the package to your composer.json file?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: @wiwa1978 I updated my answer. The namespace needed to be global.

Comment: Works now perfectly. Thanks so much!